# Nestjs ClassSerializerInterceptor doesn't work

Tags: node.js, serialization, nestjs, interceptor

I want `ClassSerializerInterceptor` to make my response body match response type, currently it doesn't work and still returns all the fields that are returned from function.
Example of my response DTO:

```
export class SignedInUserDTO extends PartialType(
  PickType(User, ['id', 'email', 'role']),
) {
  @IsString()
  accessToken: string;
}
```

For my DTO I also tried to attach `@Exclude()`, but this had no effect.

Controller:

```
 @Post('sign-in')
  async signUp(@Body() signInUserDto: SignInUserDTO): Promise<SignedInUserDTO> {
    return this.authService.signIn(signInUserDto);
  }
```

How I set up interceptor in `main.ts`:

```
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));
```

I also tried to attach it directly to route like this:

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
```

But neither method works. I really have no clue what is wrong here, any thoughts?

UPDATE:

I've played around for a few more hours, it's working with another route which just returns user from database, fields marked with `@Exclude()` are not returned, which is correct, yet it still doesn't work for other routes, even using `plainToInstance()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is happening because plain object is returned from response, but `ClassSerializerInterceptor` can work only with classes.

I used approach like this: https://gist.github.com/ibayazit/dee57afc274297490e7265bcf4da63ab

And now for every route that returns plain object I attach `@Serialize()` decorator.

Still I'd prefer to set this up on global level, any suggestions on that are
higly appreciated.